# Javascript, counting years and days since 1970-01-01 until today

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to count the numbers of years and the days(that remains after the years is counted). So it shows how long its gone in years+days since 1970-01-01. Right now I'm only able to get the years right, and I'm not sure if the days are correct. They are both separated, I need them to in some way make var diffDays and diffYear. A calculation so the computer gets that after counting years, to do minus numbers of years in days and show how many days thats left, since today.

```html
<head>
<script>

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  document.write(today);
  
  function myFunction() {
  
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
    var firstDate = new Date(1970,01,01);
    var secondDate = new Date();

    var diffYear = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)/365));
  
  
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));
  
    
    document.getElementById("antalYear").innerHTML = diffYear;
  
    document.getElementById("antalDagar").innerHTML = diffDays;
  }
  
</script>

</head>


<body onload="myFunction()">

  <p>
    Numbers of years and days:
    <h3>
      <span id="antalYear"></span>
      years and 
      <span id="antalDagar"></span> 
      days
    </h3> Since: 1970,01,01.
  </p>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. It fails to take leap years into consideration, for one thing.

Comment: You might want to do some research on dates. '1 year' is not exactly 365 days.

Comment: What you can do instead is just take `secondDate().getYear() - firstDate().getYear()` to get the year difference. The days are a little trickier, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with using a library I would recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

It's the go to for handling almost anything related to dates.

```js
var oldDate = moment("1970-01-01", "YYYY-MM-DD")

var today = moment()
console.log(today.diff(oldDate, "years"));
console.log(today.diff(oldDate, "days"));

$(".years").append(today.diff(oldDate, "years"))

$(".days").append(today.diff(oldDate, "days"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Years:<div class="years"></div>
</br>
Days:<div class="days"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer shouldn't rely on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP, nor on a library that is irrelevant to the question (i.e. jQuery). It also doesn't answer the question "*…and the days (that remain after the years is counted)*".

Answer (score 0):

For the number of years since 1970, just subtract it from the current year:

```
date.getFullYear() - 1970
```

For the number of days since the beginning of the year, you can subtract a date for 1 Jan in the current year from the current date to get milliseconds, then divide by ms per day. However, that doesn't allow for daylight saving changeovers which might affect the result. If you want to round up, so that any time on 1 January is 1 day, etc. then you can set the time to 12 noon, divide by ms/day and round up (or round down and add one). That gives you the day number of the year.

E.g.

```js
function dayOfYear(date) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  var d = new Date(date);
  // Get time value for start of 1 Jan in date year
  var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0);
  // Get number of days, rounded up
  return Math.ceil((d.setHours(12,0,0,0) - yearStart) / 8.64e7);
}

// Day of year for current date
console.log('Current day number: ' + dayOfYear(new Date()));

// Day of year for 31 Dec 2016
console.log('Day number for 31 Dec 2016: ' + dayOfYear(new Date(2016, 11, 31))); // 366
```

If you want the number of completed days (so 1 Jan is 0, 2 Jan is 1, etc.) just subtract 1 from the result (or use *Math.floor* instead of *Math.ceil*).